# how to find full mitochondrial genome of plants in GenBank?

Tags: genomics, mitochondria

I am searching for full mitochondrial genome of a species of `Malvaceae` family.
To be more specific, I need the genus *[`Corchorus`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corchorus)*. But I could not find the location where it is in gene bank. After searching in google, I found [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/ORGANELLES/mztax_short.html), but here I did not found anything for plant.

Can you help me to locate its actual location?

#### Scientific classification from Wikipedia:

Kingdom:    Plantae
(unranked): Angiosperms
(unranked): Eudicots
(unranked): Rosids
Order:  Malvales
Family: Malvaceae
Subfamily:  Grewioideae
Genus:  Corchorus
L.

Comment: Related post: http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/16168/3340

Comment: I think, manetsus wants sequence , not definitions. Plus link given in that post is for Human Mitochondria database not plant. The species he/she looking for is not available on NCBI (at least I couldn't find it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search a genome for [*Corchorus*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=Corchorus) on Genbank you will only find genomes of a virus related to it. There is not a lot of plant genomes available and for the ones you can find it is quite often the case that there is only the chloroplast assembled.

So unfortunately the most plausible answer to your question is: It is not yet available for this plant. There are only very few hits for [*Malvales*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=Malvales) at all, and none of them seems to have the mitochondrium assembled.

There might be chances that there is a specific project/database for Malvales or mitochondria, where you could search, but I am not aware of one.

Answer (score 1):

Is this one? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/38606?genome_assembly_id=233326

What I did was Google: "search mitochondria genome BLAST"

and clicked the first page for me "Organelle Genome Resources". I then selected

"Browse by Organism" on the lefthand side, which took me to a new page.

I then entered in the top left text box the phrase "Malvaceae" and up came a scroll down list from the text box of choices for the text field.

I chose the first "Malvaceae (taxid:3629)" and upon clicking that, 26 entries came up for organelles. Two of which were from Mitochondria under the "Type" column.

The other entry being: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/10704?genome_assembly_id=233221

Sorry if I  was totally off base, I am just a undergrad.

Comment: No. This is wrong species.

Comment: To be more specific, I need the genus *[Corchorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corchorus)*, you can see the scientific classification there.